# Layover at DEL T3 Holiday Inn

Tags: layovers, del

We are arriving New Delhi DEL on a British Airways flight from London late in the evening and departing early the next morning for Kathmandu on an Air India flight. These flights are booked separately. We are in the airport only perhaps eight hours, but overnight, and would like to stay in a hotel room. The in-terminal Holiday Inn Express naturally caught our attention, but [the exact setup of this hotel is a little confusing](http://www.hiexdelhiairport.com/), and emailing the property does not yield clear answers.

Specifically, the advice on the property website for international transit passengers is to ensure that baggage is checked through, so it will not be collected at DEL. As we are travelling on separate tickets, this is not possible -- we *will* need to pickup luggage, and clear immigration (which I am aware means getting a visa).

The question is, what happens next? Can we use the "landside/domestic wing" of the hotel without a boarding pass for a domestic flight? Can we bring our luggage to the room, and get back to the check-in area the next morning? Is there a better solution I'm not aware of (besides altering our flights which is not an option at this point)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be worried about it much. There will be a Holiday Inn guy who would be waiting for you at the arrivals. Either he will lead you to the hotel or direct you to the desk, where another person will lead you to the hotel.

If you are departing on a domestic flight, not sure if Kathmandu is domestic or international, it is really a twisty way as you will sort of exit security and get back in. I did it once an it was really a pain, but the Holiday Inn guy was there with me and it helped. Same when you exit the hotel to catch your flight. Another Holiday Inn guy will lead you back to the terminals. Everything is inside the airport and you never exit. And they will guide you where to find the next Holiday Inn person or the hotel.

I have done it twice now and twice I have found the Holiday Inn guy at the arrivals and before you reach immigration.

Comment: Kathmandu is international (Nepal), which is why I suspect this might be complicated.

Comment: Nepal is a gray area as regards to being international/national from India as Indian citizens don't require a visa for Nepal except for an identification document which does include a passport too.